# How to pass string value to another form's load event in C #

Tags: c#

(I'm currently taking c#, but I've never taken any of the prerequisite classes, so please forgive my limited understanding.)

The answers I've seen so far aren't what I need for this project.

This is what I have so far:

//Form1

```
private void printToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string strStatus = "";
            if (rdoMarr.Checked)
            {
                strStatus = "Married";
            }
            else
            {
                strStatus = "Single";
            }
                    string strPrint = "Marital Status = " + strStatus + "\n Pay         Period =" + cbPayPd.Text + "\n Dependents =" + cbAllow.Text + "\n Gross = " + txtGross.Text + "\n Fit = " + txtFit.Text + "\n Soc = " + txtSoc.Text + "\n Med = " + txtMed.Text + "\n Net = " + txtNet.Text;
            var form2 = new Print(strPrint);
            form2.Show();
        }
```

What needs to go onto my Form2 to receive this string?

Comment: If you know this is a duplicate question, why don't you read the answers of the other questions?

Comment: So just store it in a variable that both your Form and MessageBox can access

Comment: See my two form project : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34975508/reach-control-from-another-page-asp-net

Comment: I was unable to take the prerequisite classes, so I'm unfamiliar with a lot of the terminology. I tried to comment on previous questions to get more specific answers, but I'm new here, and my reputation needs to be higher to do so.

Comment: *Update* My instructor showed me a much more efficient way to do this than what has been shown in the links you guys provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to do this. The one below is not what I would recommend, but I think it's the easiest to understand.

Here's one way to do this:

1. Create a public static property on your `Form1` class to hold the value of this variable
2. Use the property from step #1 for the `MessageBox` text
3. Create a method that will update this property with the text you want
4. Call the method in #3 when your form loads
5. Create a common `EventHandler` method that calls the method in #2
6. Hook up the `TextChanged` event of the `TextBox` objects whose text is used in your string to the common `EventHandler` created in #4
7. Reference the property in #2 when your `Form2` loads

   - My example assumes you have a `Label` named `label1` on the Form that you want to update with the text

Here's how:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    // 1. This class-level variable will hold our string
    public static string PrintMessage { get; private set; }

    // 2. Reference your strPrint variable for the MessageBox as you were before
    private void printToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(PrintMessage);
    }

    // 3. This method will update our string with values from TextBoxes
    private void UpdateText()
    {
        PrintMessage = "Gross = " + txtGross.Text + "\n Fit = " + txtFit.Text +
            "\n Soc = " + txtSoc.Text + "\n Med = " + txtMed.Text +
            "\n Net = " + txtNet.Text;
    }

    // 4. Call our update method when the Form loads
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        UpdateText();
    }

    // 5. This EventHandler just calls our update method
    private void CommonTextChangedEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        UpdateText();
    }

    // I have a `button1` on my Form1, and clicking this button shows Form2
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var form2 = new Form2();
        form2.Show();
    }
```

Now, hook up the event handler. The easiest way is:

1. One at a time, select one of the textboxes whose `Text` is used in our string
2. In the Properties window, click the `Events` button (looks like a lightning bolt)
3. Choose the `TextChanged` event, and assign our new method to it

[image]

Now, in your `Form2` class, you should be able to reference the `Form1` property you created in #1:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label1.Text = Form1.PrintMessage;
    }
```

To test it, just run the project, change the text in the text boxes, and click the button to load Form2

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your example was very helpful. You even made it easier for me to understand what I'd been reading on previous questions and their answers.